# Using Java to open excel then to read xml and then save as xls

Tags: java, xml, excel

My response from server is in xml format, I am able to open this file using excel and excel will auto generate the table for me. After that I can save this file as xls, and my java program is capable of retreiving those information through loops. My question is how do I use java code to replace the step " open xml using excel, wait for auto generated table, then save this file as xls". I tried several ways, it is not going to work, if I open the xml file using java code, it will give me invalid header error. Any help would be greatly appreciated. My code is as follow:

```
FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream("Y:\\xx\\xx .xml");  
 POIFSFileSystem fs = new POIFSFileSystem( input );  
  HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(fs);
  FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("Y:\\xx\\xx.xls") ;
  wb.write(fos);
  fose.close();
```

This will give me invalid header error, please help.

Comment: Another alternative would be to parse XML directly, and write to excel. I am capable of doing that, just wondering if other options are available.